# Having problems with else statement

Tags: android, button, if-statement, onclicklistener

I am currently trying to make an order game. The user had to press the buttons in the order given. How ever I am having some problem with the `else` statement. This is my code.

```
private OnClickListener click2 = new OnClickListener() {
        List<Integer> mClickedButtonIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        mClickedButtonIds.add(v.getId());       
        if (mClickedButtonIds.size() > 4 ) 
        { 
            mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);            
            int[] mDesiredOrder = new int[] { R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2, R.id.imageButton3, R.id.imageButton4 };

            if (mClickedButtonIds.get(0) == mDesiredOrder[0] 
                && mClickedButtonIds.get(1) == mDesiredOrder[1] 
                && mClickedButtonIds.get(2) == mDesiredOrder[2]
                && mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3]
                )
            {
                tv1.setText("Correct");

            }

            else 
            {
                 tv1.setText("Wrong");
            }

        }    
    }   
    };
```

If I play the game for the first time, the `else` statement work perfectly. But if I play the game again without closing the application, the `else` statement start to have problem. Every single button I press will come out the `else` statement which make my `tv1` to set text as **Wrong**. But the `if`statement still work perfectly. Means that although it keep on set text as **Wrong** but if I click the final button of the correct order it will set text as **Correct**. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `private OnClickListener click2 = new OnClickListener() {
        List<Integer> mClickedButtonIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();` do this in onResume(), not onCreate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you didn't create a new `OnClickListener` every game, so the `ArrayList` was not cleared.

Comment: See [`ArrayList.clear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()).

Comment: okay thanks a lot after clearing the `arraylist` it become good. However I still have some problem. This game only need to click 4 time, however I need to click it 5 time in order for it to work if I play the game for the 2nd time after clearing the `arraylist`. Cause if I didn't clear the `arraylist`, the 1st time, I need to click 5 timse but 2nd time, I only need to click 4 times. Is there any method to solve this.

Comment: Does not work. If i change to 3, the word `Correct` did not come out even if I press it in order. I think is due to `mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3]` requirement is not fulfilled.

Comment: I guess I will just need to add another button for the user to click for nothing. Anyway thanks for helping me to solve my `arraylist` problem.

Comment: `mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);` <-- it's because you removed the first element...!?

Comment: it seems like without the `mClickedButtonIds.clear();` it will not work

Comment: I solved my problem. I looks like I need to change to ` if (mClickedButtonIds.size() >= 4 )` and remove `mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Try Else If for the second block rather than just " Else "

Comment: but if I use `else if` then what is the condition for it?